# The resource cannot be found MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have uploaded my site on server. And there is an error occurred. My site url is http://vintageoverseas.org/. Here is a page that's url is http://vintageoverseas.org/en/Blog but when i click on `read more` button `Blog title` then `The resource cannot be found.` In this action name is `BlogPost` and when i change it to `Post` than this error is occurred as

```
The view 'Post' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Home/Post.aspx
~/Views/Home/Post.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Post.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Post.ascx
~/Views/Home/Post.cshtml
~/Views/Home/Post.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/Post.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/Post.vbhtml
```

And my controller name is `Home` and it's code is

```
  public ActionResult BlogPost(long? Id)
        {
            BlogModel blog = new BlogModel();
            blog = b.GetBlogDetail(Id.ToString());
            List<TagModel> tags = new List<TagModel>();
            tags = b.GetBlogTags(blog.blog_id.ToString());
            blog.tag_name_list = tags.Select(m => m.tag_name).ToList();
            List<ImageModel> image = new List<ImageModel>();
            image = b.GetBlogImages(blog.blog_id.ToString());
            blog.img_path_list = image.Select(m => m.path).ToList();
            blog.parent_cat_id = b.GetMainParent(blog.cat_id);
            return View(blog);
        }
```

And view name is `BlogPost`

**And routing is**

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Custom",
                url: "en/{action}/{id}/{Title}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", 
                    id = UrlParameter.Optional, Title = UrlParameter.Optional, en = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            ); 
        }
```

Comment: Do you have an name attribute decorating your action? Or do you mare a `RedirectToAction` call from a `Post` action?

Comment: This `en` is for routing @AndreiV and there is no action named as 'post'

Comment: Have you considered possibility that view with name "Post.XXX" does not exist? It looks like error message says so... It is not exactly clear what you are asking - I assume you know that default view name is name of the action... so not sure what help you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your BlogPost action resides in HomeController.cs? Or is there a controller named "en"?

You might need a `{controller}` parameter in your first route, and then modify your anchor to utilize controller as `@Html.ActionLink("Read More...", "BlogPost", "ControllerName", new {id="123", null);`

Try using route debugger - it can be turned on and off using a web.config switch after installed: https://www.nuget.org/packages/routedebugger